# What happens during freezing?

Tags: thermodynamics, freezing

I did an experiment investigating the Mpemba effect and I found that a contributing factor to why hot water freezes faster than cold water is due to the amount of time the water takes to freeze. As in during a phase change, the water stays at a constant temperature until the whole thing freezes, so once the whole thing freezes, the temperature starts to drop, so from the point where it hits the freezing temperature to the point just before the temperature drops is what I'm referring to.

I found that in the cooler temperatures, it stayed at the "freezing stage" for longer than the hotter water. I can't really find an explanation online as to what actually happens during this stage and what can affect the time it takes to complete this stage.So I'm just curious to know if there's anything which affects this stage.

Comment: How much ice did you end up with?

Comment: @JonCuster I did it in small batches and each sample was 50ml and after every sample, I just dumped the ice into the sink, so I don't really know how much

Comment: The reality of the Mpemba effect is in fact hotly disputed: https://www.nature.com/articles/srep37665 and should not be taken for granted.

Comment: Nature: We conclude that despite our best efforts, we were not able to make observations of any physical effects which could reasonably be described as the Mpemba effect. Moreover, we have shown that all data (with the only exceptions coming from a single study) reporting to be observations of the Mpemba effect within existing studies fall just above the Mpemba effect line, i.e. the difference in the cooling times between the hot and cold samples is marginal.

Comment: We have shown (Fig. 3) that much of the data reporting to be observations of the Mpemba effect were from studies not reporting the height at which temperatures were measured7,14,20,21,22,23 and that the conclusions drawn from these data could have been altered by simply recording temperatures without precisely monitoring the height. Indeed, all the data which lie just above the Mpemba effect line in Fig. 3 (including data for which the temperautre measurement height was carefully monitored and reported17,24,28) are, [...]

Comment: [...] by the very nature of experiments, subject to some degree of uncertainty which may ultimately affect whether the observed results are recorded as an apparent observation of the Mpemba effect or not.

Comment: @Gert Doesn't really help me, does it?

Comment: @BrienLim It should help understanding the 'Mpemba effect' you claim to have observed is almost certainly not real. Any subsequent conclusions you might have drawn are also likely to be questionable.

Comment: @Gert My main question is what happens during the freezing stage. Not "does the mpemba effect occur?" the mpemba effect is simply the observation that hot water freezes faster than cold water and i did observe that in my experiment

Comment: @BrienLim - so you did not weigh the samples before and after? So, what could cause a weight difference, and how would that impact your measurements?

Comment: @BrienLim Your 'main question' derives directly from your claimed observation of the Mpemba effect. Re. the latter, stating 'I did observe that in my experiment', w/o anything like a statistical analysis is very unconvincing and smacks of confirmation bias.

Comment: @Gert Confirmation bias? It's not very hard to interpret data which just tells the time it takes for water to freeze at different temperatures. For example, if water at 80 degrees celsius takes 1h to freeze, but water at 30 degrees celsius takes 1h 30min to freeze, I would say that that's evidence of the Mpemba effect already and not due to  confirmation bias

Comment: @JonCuster I totally forgot about weighing them, but what I did was put a layer of oil on the top and then put a stopper on the boiling tube

Comment: @BrienLim Without your experiment protocol there's nothing to discuss here. Your nice round numbers are highly suspect though. I don't wish to discuss the matter any further. All the best.

Comment: @Gert those aren't my exact numbers, I was giving an example. All I'm asking is what happens during freezing. Me raising the Mpemba effect is to give context of why I'm asking. All you had to do is answer the question, you don't even need my data